# DatePickerIOS not working because of design in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm facing issue that when I choose date from DatePickerIOS it allows me to choose month but when I scroll `date` and `year` it doesn't allow me to choose/scroll and it is caused due to width problem. The code is given below:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <TouchableOpacity 
       activeOpacity={0.8} 
       onPress={this._selectFromDate}
       style={s.flex_direction_row}
   >
        <Text style={s.detail_txtinput_drpdown}>
           {this.state.from_d}
        </Text>
        <Icon style={s.calendar_icon} name="md-calendar" size={33} color="#00796b"/>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   {
        this.state.showFromDatePicker ?
           <DatePickerIOS
              date={this.state.from_date}
              onDateChange={(from_date)=>this._onFromDateChange(from_date)}
              mode="date"
           />
        :
          null
   }
</View>
```

when I use `flex:1` then it looks like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS7fp.png

and when I remove `flex:1` it looks like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oktw.png

in second image I can select/scroll `month(April)` but I can't select/scroll `date` and `year`.
Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just change place of `DatePickerIOS`'s `View` I removed it from `<TouchableOpacity>`'s `View` and put it in main `<View>` after `<View style={{flex:1}}>`. It solved my problem.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <TouchableOpacity 
        activeOpacity={0.8} 
        onPress={this._selectFromDate}
        style={s.flex_direction_row}
     >
        <Text style={s.detail_txtinput_drpdown}>
           {this.state.from_d}
        </Text>
        <Icon style={s.calendar_icon} name="md-calendar" size={33} color="#00796b"/>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
<View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  {
    this.state.showFromDatePicker ?
       <DatePickerIOS
          date={this.state.from_date}
          onDateChange={(from_date)=>this._onFromDateChange(from_date)}
          mode="date"
       />
    :
      null
  }
</View>
```